# Deriving the dual linear program.

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems

The last optimization subject I took was so long ago, so I just grabbed a guide online to derive and verify the following claim from a lecture note

[image]

This is the guide: http://pierrepinson.com/31761/Literature/lahaie2008-lpprimer.pdf

I followed the steps but all I got is this:

> The dual would be:
>
> $\underset{\lambda, \mu \geq 0}{\text{max }} -\lambda^Td + \mu^Tb  \\
>  \mu^TA - \lambda^TD = c^T$

which is not quite the form in the note. I'm not sure if I got it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim in the lecture note is correct.  Arthur Benjamin's [S-O-B method](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2132755.pdf?casa_token=7JzPfqmqY6AAAAAA:sJoHGZEP-sqRN1MbchgfPgRkh38BLR39x03y2L_rRZBpLSq1D_Jm06WLGnl1fxhhtd45g1wa3qJOHn1Ef5Q04Y6Nm6kfk6LYc5kljI5SaNLBTyVSDu66) is useful for obtaining the dual LP.